# How to get the result in single List?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm creating Fare Estimator on the basis of a Codefight Code challenge.

That can tell you how much your ride will cost before you request it. It works by passing approximated ride distance and ride time through this **formula**:

**`(Cost per minute) * (ride time) + (Cost per mile) * (ride distance)`**

---

**Example**

**For**

- ride_time = 30,
- ride_distance = 7,
- cost_per_minute = [0.2, 0.35, 0.4, 0.45]
- cost_per_mile = [1.1, 1.8, 2.3, 3.5], **the output should be**
- **fareEstimator**(ride_time, ride_distance, cost_per_minute,
  cost_per_mile) = [13.7, 23.1, 28.1, 38]

**Where Output must be in a list**

---

**Since:**

- 30 * 0.2 + 7 * 1.1 = 6 + 7.7 = 13.7
- 30 * 0.35 + 7 * 1.8 = 10.5 + 12.6 = 23.1
- 30 * 0.4 + 7 * 2.3 = 12 + 16.1 = 28.1
- 30 * 0.45 + 7 * 3.5 = 13.5 + 24.5 = 38

---

### Here is my Code:

```
def fareEstimator(ride_time, ride_distance, cost_per_minute, cost_per_mile):

    for cpm, cpmile in zip(cost_per_minute, cost_per_mile):
        result = round(( ride_time * cpm ) + ( ride_distance * cpmile ), 1)
        print([result])

fareEstimator(30, 7, [0.2, 0.35, 0.4, 0.45], [1.1, 1.8, 2.3, 3.5])
```

### Its output

```
[13.7]
[23.1]
[28.1]
[38.0]
```

I've tried using List Comprehension where I am getting `TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable`

Now please help me to get the result in a single list Like this.

### [13.7, 23.1, 28.1, 38]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of printing, append to a list that you then return:

```
result = []
for cpm, cpmile in zip(cost_per_minute, cost_per_mile):
    value = round(ride_time * cpm + ride_distance * cpmile, 1)
    result.append(value)
return result
```

This is easily converted to a list comprehension; just put the `result` expression at the front:

```
return [round(ride_time * cpm + ride_distance * cpmile, 1)
        for cpm, cpmile in zip(cost_per_minute, cost_per_mile)]
```

Demo:

```
>>> def fareEstimator(ride_time, ride_distance, cost_per_minute, cost_per_mile):
...     return [round(ride_time * cpm + ride_distance * cpmile, 1)
...             for cpm, cpmile in zip(cost_per_minute, cost_per_mile)]
...
>>> fareEstimator(30, 7, [0.2, 0.35, 0.4, 0.45], [1.1, 1.8, 2.3, 3.5])
[13.7, 23.1, 28.1, 38.0]
```

Note that this *returns* the new list, if you still need to print this result, do so where you called `fareEstimator()`.

Comment: But Output must be [13.7, 23.1, 28.1, 38] not [13.7, 23.1, 28.1, 38.0]

Comment: Why would that be? Rounding produces floats, always. Creating an integer just because the decimal portion is 0 does not make much sense and would be inconsistent.

Comment: the behavior of codefight might be because it's a javascript or similar thing

Comment: I'm not that familiar with codefight; make sure you *actually solved the problem*. Is rounding really needed for example?

Answer (score 1):

A simplest (editing-wise) approach is to just replace the `print([result])` with `yield result` and your `fareEstimator` would become [a generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) function.

If you need a list (e.g. for indexed access) and not just some iterable, call it like this:

```
print(list(fareEstimator(...)))
```

Or, if you know always need a list you may also do it like this:

```
def fareEstimator(ride_time, ride_distance, cost_per_minute, cost_per_mile):
    result = []
    for cpm, cpmile in zip(cost_per_minute, cost_per_mile):
        value = round((ride_time * cpm) + (ride_distance * cpmile), 1)
        result.append(value)
    return result
```

Or, better, the same written as a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
def fareEstimator(ride_time, ride_distance, cost_per_minute, cost_per_mile):
    return [round((ride_time * cpm) + (ride_distance * cpmile), 1)
            for cpm, cpmile in zip(cost_per_minute, cost_per_mile)]
```

And

```
print(fareEstimator(...))
```

Would print that list.

Comment: Op seems to be learning how to use lists; not sure introducing generators right away is a good idea.

Comment: @ValentinLorentz yes, you're right. That wast just what came to my mind as a simplest change - editing-wise (least edits necessary). A list comprehension is probably the best choice for OP - it returns a familiar `list`, and it's extremely widely used in Python and certainly worth learning about.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is here:

```
print([result])
```

For each result, you create a list containing only the result, and print it.
What you want to do seems to be in the lines of creating an empty list, and add each result to it.

Like this:

```
def fareEstimator(ride_time, ride_distance, cost_per_minute, cost_per_mile):
    results = []
    for cpm, cpmile in zip(cost_per_minute, cost_per_mile):
        result = round(( ride_time * cpm ) + ( ride_distance * cpmile ), 1)
        results.append(result)
    print(results)
```

See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html to know more about the operations you can do on a list.

Comment: can you please suggest me some good sites where I can find more coding challenges to make my programming concepts more clear..

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use list comprehension and return the result from the function:

```
def fareEstimator(ride_time, ride_distance, cost_per_minute, cost_per_mile):    
    return [round(( ride_time * cpm ) + ( ride_distance * cpmile ), 1) 
            for cpm, cpmile in zip(cost_per_minute, cost_per_mile)]

>>> fareEstimator(30, 7, [0.2, 0.35, 0.4, 0.45], [1.1, 1.8, 2.3, 3.5])
[13.7, 23.1, 28.1, 38.0]
```